# SQL query to select the same field from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have three tables defined as this in the schema

```
donuts (name: string, price: integer) 
grocery (no: string, gname: string, minCredit: integer) 
distributor (dname: string, gno: string, deliverydate: date)
```

distributor.dname and distributor.gno are foreign keys that reference donuts and grocery which keys are name and no respectivey I am having trouble with 2 queries I am trying to write:

I am trying to display pairs of donuts which can be found at the same grocery store (i.e. all stores who carry one donuts are taken by the other and viceversa). The output schema should be (donutname1, donutname2)

What I have tried is:

```
select d.name as donutname1, d.name as donutname2
from donuts d, grocery g, distributor dd
where d.name IN  
    (select  d.name 
     from donuts d, grocery g, distributor dd 
     where d.name = dd.name)
```

This seems to wrong and seems to be giving me the wrong result. How could I query for both names and get the result?

Comment: Likely the problem you are having is because you are creating a cartesian product table and are not aligning the rows properly. Try switching to `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Also, adding some sample data and expected results would really help here, I don't fully understand what you mean by "all stores who carry one donuts are taken by the other"

Comment: MySQL or SQLite? They are different products and implement SQL differently. Can you pls provide some sample data and expected outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Try to experiment a bit with the following using your data:

```
SELECT aa.name AS donutname1, bb.name AS donutname2
FROM dunuts AS aa
INNER JOIN donuts AS bb
ON aa.name = bb.name
INNER JOIN distributor AS cc
ON aa.name = cc.dname
INNER JOIN distributor AS dd
ON bb.name = cc.dname
WHERE cc.gno = dd.gno;
```